# Gaussian Bayes Classification with dependent variables..

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, machine-learning

Gaussian Bayes Classification:

two classes: $y \in \{-1,+1\}$

Dependencies for a vector of features ($x_1,x_2,x_3)$:
$x_1=z,x_2=2z,x_3=t+3$,
where

$$P(z\mid y=+1) = \aleph(z;\mu_+,1),\qquad P(z\mid y=-1) = \aleph(z;\mu_-,1)$$

$$P(t\mid y=+1) = \aleph(t;\nu_+,1), \qquad P(t\mid y=-1) = \aleph(t;\nu_-,1)$$

$z$ and $t$ are conditionally independent given $y$.

Prior: $P(y=+1) = P(y= -1) = 0.5$

What is the likelihood $p(x_1,x_2,x_3\mid y) $ for each $y$?

Comment: The statement "$z$" is conditionally independent of $t\mid y$" arouses some suspicion that a certain misunderstanding is at work that I've seen among people posting on things like this.  It's as if someone writing such a sentence thinks that there is something called $t\mid y$ and that $z$ is conditionally independent of that.  That is incorrect.  Rather, there is something called independence given $y$. The random variables $z$ and $t$ are independent of each other given $y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: actually i meant z is independent of t given y

Comment: The misunderstanding that sometimes happens is that people parse the sentence as "$z$ is conditionally independent of ($t\mid y$)", whereas it should be parsed as "($z$ is independent of $t$)${}\mid y$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: correct.. could you change that?